# Transfer from Incheon airport to Gimpo and vice versa

Tags: airport-transfer, icn, gmp

I am travelling from UAE to South Korea (Gwangju). I have a flight to Seoul (Incheon airport)  then from that airport to  Gimpo Airport in order to fly to Gwangju

Return ticket will be from Gimpo to Incheon  airport.

I am trying to find the different possibilities car/bus/train to go from Incheon to Gimpo  like duration as I am afraid to miss flight, and cost. Which one might be better?

Comment: Take AREX train. Easy, inexpensive and convenient. Yes, some walking required to the station @ Gimpo. Signs are easy to follow.

Answer (score 9):

You can take the train from Incheon to Gimpo.

The line is named [AREX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AREX)

It takes [34 min and costs 3550 ₩ (~3 € / $)](http://www.arex.or.kr/).

[Itinerary on smrt.co.kr](http://www.smrt.co.kr/program/cyberStation/main2.jsp?lang=e&sname2=Incheon+Intl.+Airport&stcd2=4213&sname3=Gimpo+Intl.+Airport&stcd3=4207&x=100&y=2)

Answer (score 8):

**Take the train**. The [A'REX](http://www.arex.or.kr/) will whisk you from Incheon Airport straight to Gimpo Airport in 35 minutes for just 3,750 won (~US$3.50), with trains every 10 minutes or so. Note that you'll need to take the regular "All Stop Train" (commuter) service; the express goes straight to Seoul Station.

There are also [bus services](http://www.airport.kr/pa/en/a/3/1/1/index.jsp), which can be marginally faster if traffic is in your favor, but run less often and cost about twice the price (7,500 won).

Comment: I took this last year and signage is excellent and in four languages, including English.  It will be easy to find.