# Minimum time to transfer between Incheon and Gimpo airports

Tags: airport-transfer, short-connections

I purchased a ticket from Seattle to Tokyo with a 3 hour layover in Incheon airport in Seoul, South Korea. After purchase the airline canceled the ICN-HND flight and replaced it in my itinerary with a Gimpo to Haneda flight; however, the new flight leaves only 1 hour 50 minutes after the first is scheduled to land. Transferring via a separate airport will require not only the transit time between airports, but going through immigration and customs at ICN, and checkin and security at GMP. Is 2 hours enough time for that process?

[Transfer from Incheon airport to Gimpo and vice versa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44805/transfer-from-incheon-airport-to-gimpo-and-vice-versa) covers the mechanics of transferring between the airports but not the minimum time to do so.

Comment: That's [not nearly enough time](https://www.koreanair.com/global/en/traveling/airports-transit/connecting-flight-info/minimum-connection-time.html).

Comment: I called the OTA and they gave us a SEA-ICN ICN-NRT flight. The connection time is only 50 minutes but at least that connection is theoretically possible.

Comment: Someone met us at the gate, and escorted us to the front of the transit security line. So we made our ~50 minute Incheon connection no problem.

Comment: @stannius any chance you could create an answer then for the question and accept it?

Comment: I could but @MichaelHampton deserves the credit.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate; I already found that answer and included an explanation of how I think this question is different. That said, if the other question was edited to include the additional information of how long the intrer-airport transfer would take, it would make that question a one-stop shop; and I'd be fine if this one was closed.

Answer (score 4):

Korean Air has a [table of transfer times / minimum connection times](https://www.koreanair.com/global/en/traveling/airport-check-in/connecting-flight-info/minimum-connection-time.html) on their site.

Considering you have an international (Incheon) to international (Gimpo) transfer, their site oddly doesn't cover this, but does cover International flight (Incheon Airport) > Domestic flight (Gimpo Airport), which has a minimum connection time of 150 minutes. Give you're going international, that's at least another 20 minutes if you're lucky, but even ignoring that, 150 minutes is more than your current gap of 110 minutes.

Short answer: You need at least 2.5 hours.

Comment: I assume Korean Air doesn't fly any international flights out of Gimpo.

Comment: @stannius hmm, quite possibly. Times still apply, at least, so at least their table is of use.

Comment: @stannius They do, but only short-haul regional flights to Tokyo, Osaka, Beijing and Shanghai.  As all are also served from Incheon and quite frequently at that, doing an int'l-int'l cross-airport transfer like this would be pointless, inconvenient and rather unusual.