# Travel from Gimpo airport to Incheon airport during night

Tags: transit-visas, airport-transfer

I am travelling from Osaka airport, Japan to New Delhi, India via Gimpo Airport and Incheon airport. I am arriving at Gimpo International Airport around 18:30 and on the next day at 11:30 morning I have a flight from Incheon International Airport. So I would spend around 16 ~ 17 hours in Korea. I hold an Indian passport and Japan visa.
My questions are:

(1) Do I require the transit visa and from where I would get it (Gimpo Airport or Korean Embassy in Osaka, Japan)?

(2) How would I transfer from Gimpo to Incheon airport, what would be the fare and how much time it takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) Do I require the transit visa and from where I would get it (Gimpo Airport or Korean Embassy in Osaka, Japan)?

Depending on your citizenship, if you are not visa free to Korea you will need a transit visa as your layover is longer than 6 hours and you will be switching airports.

You would apply at the Korean embassy in Japan.

> (2) How would I transfer from Gimpo to Incheon airport, what would be the fare and how much time it takes?

See this guide here:

- [Transfer from Incheon airport to Gimpo and vice versa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44805/transfer-from-incheon-airport-to-gimpo-and-vice-versa)

> You can take the train from Incheon to Gimpo.
>
> The line is named [AREX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AREX)
>
> It takes [34 min and costs 3550 ₩ (~3 € / $)](http://www.arex.or.kr/)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the second of your questions, there is a train between the two airports that takes approximately 35-40 minutes. It costs approximately 3500 Won.

I've had a look regarding your first question and I can find no evidence that visas are available on arrival in Gimpo. As an Indian national you would require a visa to enter Korea (which you must do to change airports). Therefore, you would need to apply for a transit or tourist visa from the nearest Korean Embassy or Consulate to your residence.